# Can't change DEVMODE of a printer

Tags: c#, printing, intptr, dev-mode

I need to change `DEVMODE` of printer for current printing task to pass standard and device-specific settings. I do the following:

```
PrintDocument d = new PrintDocument();
d.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = "Microsoft XPS Document Writer"; // example printer name           
byte[] devmode_data; // contains a valid value that is obtained from registry
IntPtr devmode = IntPtr.Zero;
GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(devmode_data, GCHandleType.Pinned);
try
{
    devmode = handle.AddrOfPinnedObject();
    if (devmode != IntPtr.Zero) d.PrinterSettings.SetHdevmode(devmode);
}
finally
{
    if (handle.IsAllocated) handle.Free();
}
```

It fails when I attempt to execute `PrinterSettings.SetHdevmode` with a `NullReferenceException` and without any meaningful error info. `d.PrinterSettings` is not null, the exception is thrown inside of `PrinterSettings.SetHdevmode` method.
So my question is: what is wrong? Is the `byte[]` to `IntPtr` cast wrong? Maybe `SetHdevmode` expects something other than a `byte[]` array?

I get the `byte[] devmode_data` array from the registry. It is a valid value and it is same value that is used in current printer settings.

Answer (score 1):

I modified your code in the following way, since I don't have any valid data for `devmode_data`:

```
devmode = d.PrinterSettings.GetHdevmode();
if (devmode != IntPtr.Zero) d.PrinterSettings.SetHdevmode(devmode);
```

and now there is no exception here.

Please, provide me with your data for `devmode_data` or check for your own, if it is valid or not!

Comment: How to cast PrinterSettings.GetHdevmode() to something meaningful? I've tried GCHandle.FromIntPtr() and then handle.Target, but that throws an exception.

Comment: As long as you know the size of the structure you're poiting at, you can just declare a byte array and do the cast to pointer, `(byte[] *) devmode.ToPointer()`.

Comment: (byte[] *) devmode.ToPointer() - this doesn't compile

Comment: I am sorry, I was thinking in C++! Did you try `Marshal.Copy(IntPtr source, byte[] destination, int start, int length)`?

Comment: I don't know for sure the size of the structure. I would prefer a cast to an object :) .

Answer (score 1):

`SetHdevmode` expects an `HGLOBAL`.  You can get an `HGLOBAL` from .Net via `Marshal.AllocHGlobal`.  Then, you can use `Marshal.Copy(byte[], int, IntPtr, int)` to copy from your managed byte array to the `HGLOBAL`.  See below:

```
var pDevMode = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(devmode_data.Length);
Marshal.Copy(devmode_data, 0, pDevMode, devmode_data.Length);

d.PrinterSettings.SetHdevmode(pDevMode);
Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pDevMode);
```

The byte array can be partially handled as a structure, but that will require [p/Invoke definitions](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Structures/DEVMODE.html).  The `PrinterSettings` class, however, will not accept a structure, so doing so would be unneeded in this case.  Additionally, the `DEVMODE` structure is variable length to allow for printer drivers to add additional opaque data, so it would not be possible to convert without data loss.

See [How can I save and restore `PrinterSettings`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28007554/how-can-i-save-and-restore-printersettings) for more.