# .NET Printing. Always Use Default Preferences

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, printing

I have a service which prints. Up until now the service has been printing using the WPF `System.Windows.Controls.PrintDialog.PrintDocument` method however due to various issues (performance, windows update bugs, 32 bit service on 64bit system issues etc) I am converting to use the traditional `System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument` method.

As this is running as a service I want this to always print using the default printer preferences (which include things like media settings and print speed for industrial label printer such as the Intermec/Honewell PM43)

Previously I had done this using `PrintDialog.PrintTicket = PrintQueue.DefaultPrintTicket.Clone`

However I cannot find the equivalent method in `System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument` and the service is not picking up the default printer preferences as set in the printer properties (specifically Print Speed in this case)

So what is the equivalent of `PrintDialog.PrintTicket = PrintQueue.DefaultPrintTicket.Clone` in `System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument`?

Answer (score 0):

The following question helped me find an answer
[Can't change DEVMODE of a printer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8281623/cant-change-devmode-of-a-printer?rq=1)

```
//Get the registry key containing the printer settings
var regKey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("System\\CurrentControlSet\\Control\\Print\\Printers\\" + PrinterName);
if (regKey != null)
{    
    //Get the value of the default printer preferences
    var defaultDevMode = (byte[])regKey.GetValue("Default DevMode");
    //Create a handle and populate
    var pDevMode = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(defaultDevMode.Length);
    Marshal.Copy(defaultDevMode, 0, pDevMode, defaultDevMode.Length);
    //Set the printer preferences
    pd.PrinterSettings.SetHdevmode(pDevMode);
    //Clean up
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pDevMode);
}
```